# SQL to Oracle migration with classic asp

Tags: sql-server, oracle, asp-classic

I'm working on a sql to oracle migration.
I never used classic asp and I could use some help on this.

This is the code I have now

```
<select onChange="AlterarDisabled();/*DGT();*/" name="TIPO_PLANO" id="TIPO_PLANO">
<%
    sSql = "TP_15_SP" & "'" & ENTIDADE & "'"

    set oRS = GlobaloConn.Execute(sSql)

    do while not oRS.Eof
        if oRS.Fields(0) = "04" then
        if BALCAO = "B0142" or BALCAO= "B0593" then
            %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(0)%>"><%=oRS.Fields(1)%></option><%
            end if
    else
        %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(0)%>"><%=oRS.Fields(1)%></option><%
    end if
    oRS.MoveNext
     loop

     set oRS = nothing
%>
</select>
```

and this is the sql stored procedure

```
USE [TPS]
GO
/* Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TP_15_SP] Script Date: 10/02/2013 11:09:46 */
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TP_15_SP] @CdEnt VARCHAR(4)
AS
SELECT * FROM TP_15
WHERE CDENT = @CdEnt
ORDER BY 1
```

Now I have to connect to Oracle and run a oracle function.
This is the oracle function

```
create or replace 
function TP_15_FN(v_CdEnt IN VARCHAR2) return SYS_REFCURSOR
as
l_return   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
-- This procedure was converted on Fri Apr 05 17:05:05 2013
   open l_return for SELECT * FROM TP_15
   WHERE CDENT = v_CdEnt
   ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST;

   return l_return;
END;
```

and this is the code I should use to call that function. Supposedly all I need is to change 
`sSql = "TP_15_SP" & "'" & ENTIDADE & "'"` into `sSql = "TP_15_FN(" & "'" & ENTIDADE & "')"`.
It's not working, any ideas??

```
<select onChange="AlterarDisabled();/*DGT();*/" name="TIPO_PLANO" id="TIPO_PLANO">
<%
        sSql = "TP_15_FN(" & "'" & ENTIDADE & "')"

        set oRS = GlobaloConn.Execute(sSql)

        do while not oRS.Eof
            if oRS.Fields(0) = "04" then
            if BALCAO = "B0142" or BALCAO= "B0593" then
                %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(0)%>"><%=oRS.Fields(1)%></option><%
                end if
        else
            %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(0)%>"><%=oRS.Fields(1)%></option><%
        end if
        oRS.MoveNext
         loop

         set oRS = nothing
%>
</select>
```

Comment: remove/comment on error resume next. what error do you get

Comment: Description: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Help context: 0
Help file: 
Native error: 900
Error number: -2147217900
Error source: OraOLEDB
SQL state:

Comment: after the line  sSql = "TP_15_FN(" & "'" & ENTIDADE & "')", what would get printed  if you gave response.write(sSql)

Comment: does that execute fine on your Oracle editor? or are u missing a 'call' keyword or ';'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out myself, which is nice. This is my final code.
I also had to add `PLSQLRSet=1` to my connection string.

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set oRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = GlobaloConn
    .CommandText = "TP_15_SP"
    .CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("v_CdEnt", 129 , 1 , 4, ENTIDADE)
End With

Set oRS = cmd.Execute   

do while not oRS.Eof 
    if oRS.Fields(0) = "04" then
        if BALCAO = "B0142" or BALCAO= "B0593" then
            %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(0)%>"><%=oRS.Fields(1)%></option><%
        end if
    else
        %><option value="<%=oRS.Fields(0)%>"><%=oRS.Fields(1)%></option><%
    end if

    oRS.MoveNext
loop

oRS.Close

Set oRS  = nothing
Set cmd  = nothing
```